# Searching pages in Electron?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I’m currently working on designing a program in Electron. One of the key parts to this program will be a search option. Similar to other websites that you can search the whole site for pages that match your inquiry, I would like to search within the “pages”/“html files” of my program and have it display the search results. Preferably a letter at a time display in real time so one can see results as they type, but even an option with search will do. I just need to search within my program pages, not an external site. I’m having trouble figuring out how to get started implementing this, since PHP isn’t supported in Electron. I know react can do the letter at a time real time searching, but I’m not sure how to do the search of other pages or how to parse them for searching. Any suggestions, guidelines, or frameworks to get me on the right track would be helpful. Thanks!

EDIT: I’m also aware of the webcontents.findInPage() function, but that only searches the current page, not other pages in the project path. I am fine defining which pages to search manually if I can find a way to actually search them.

Comment: Are you trying to search the HTML source, or just the text content?

Comment: @Zac the content of the page. So essentially titles, paragraphs, any element that would house text. Similar to what a search bar on a webpage, or the find feature for the current page, would do. I want to search the text after it is parsed out basically, omitting code portions or html tags

Comment: Depending on how many pages you have, and how fast the `webcontents.findInPage()` function is, it might be possible to load all the pages into some virtual environment and query them there.

Comment: @Zac if I were to do so, how generally would I set up the virtual environment to run each page with find in page? Should I try loading each page and marking it hidden, then searching? I have a feeling that if i were to do it by loading it all, it might be unnecessarily taxing on the processor and slow to finish with all the pages open. I’m probably looking at more than 10-100 pages. The program is going to be expanded in pages over time, I’m trying to get the searching framework down first.

Comment: In that case, it probably would be way too slow. If I were you, I'd find some HTML parser on the internet and get the inner HTML from each element. You could search all that through a regex, or just a normal string. It should be a lot faster than the other approach. Another way could be, when your app loads, indexing the data from all the HTML files into an object somewhere and searching that. It'd be faster, but, depending on how many files, could use a lot of RAM.

Comment: @Zac thanks for the advice. Do you have any suggestion on how I might be able to do fuzzy searching if I wanted to try and implement that on a client side thing like Electron? Does that seem like something doable? I have a feeling if I tried every piece of a search string against my html (like first word, second word, first and second, etc- the queries are likely to be multi word) it might be a bit too slow, maybe even for Regex if I tried letter at a time searching with each letter type. How do most client side programs or apps handle this usually? What is a good way to fuzzy parse if wanted?

Comment: Are the html files similar in structure? (E.g. the important text will always be in a certain div) If so, then indexing your documents and using something like [search-index](https://www.npmjs.com/package/search-index) could be the way to go. Especially if you get more and more pages over times. The nice thing about Electron is that you can use nearly any nodejs package out there.

Comment: @RoyalBingBong likely similar, since I am making them. I will give search-index a try. Is the performance generally pretty good with that package?

Comment: I linked search-index because it looked well documented, which is always important. I haven't used it (yet), so I can't say anything about performance, but I'd think that it's faster than the previous suggested method, simply because you only have to load each file once for indexing.

Comment: @RoyalBingBong Ok, thanks. I’ll take a look through the documentation and see if it will fit my usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you store all your pages in a directory like "views" you can use fs to read each file and search its content.

I have made a quick example of something you could make to do this:

```
// The directory containing all your pages
let directoryToYourPagesOrHTMLFiles = "/your/directory/";

// Require fs so you can get all the files and file content
const fs = require("fs");

// Require html-to-text so you can parse the HTML in the files
// into text so you can search on the data easier
let htmlToText = require('html-to-text'); // npm install --save html-to-text

// Run this function when a user enters a character
function userTyped(inputValue) {
    // Foreach file in the directory
    fs.readdir(directoryToYourPagesOrHTMLFiles).forEach(filename => {
        // Read the file contents
        fs.readFile(directoryToYourPagesOrHTMLFiles + "/" + filename, "utf8", (err, data) => {
            // If there was an error reading the file log it
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                // If there was no error, parse the HTML into text
                let text = htmlToText.fromString(data);

                // Perform your search on the next using the inputValue

                // Example Search:
                if(text.indexOf(inputValue) > -1) {
                    // Display the page in your search results
                    displaySearchResult(directoryToYourPagesOrHTMLFiles + "/" + filename);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}


function displaySearchResult(pagePath) {
    /*
        Add the page to a results page
     */
}
```

*I didn't test this because it did it in a rush but it shows the concept of what you need to do!*

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the response. So JavaScript/NodeJS? natively has a parser for html to text, or is this a second package I would need to set up? Thanks, I’ll see if this fits needs and adapt it to what I need if it works for my situation!

Comment: The html-to-text is a npm package not native to NodeJS so yes you will need to install it, I put the command in a comment next to the require (Line 9).